# How to use or operator in linq to sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using this code but getting an error. I want to use an `OR` operator.

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var i = dc.vins
             .Where(aa => aa.startDate < DateTime.Now)
             .Where(aa => aa.Sno > 1)
             .Select(aa => aa);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = i;
}
```

This code is working as an `"AND"` operator how can I have it act as an `"OR"` operator?

Answer (score 7):

Just put both conditions in one `Where` call, and use the normal C# `||` operator:

```
var i = dc.vins.Where(aa => aa.startDate < DateTime.Now || aa.Sno > 1);
```

Note that I've also removed your `Select` call as it wasn't doing anything useful.

Note that depending on your exact scenario, you may well want to use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`; you should carefully consider how you want time zones to be handled.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, but if we are dealing with database datetimes, then might want to consider using DateTime.UTCNow instead. Yes, using DateTime.Now is much more prettier for the users to view, but I personally prefer using the UTCNow when I interact with the database or datastore. Yes, that does mean the database does need to have datetimes stored using UTC. Thought Jon?

Comment: @TGarrett: It depends on what you're doing. *Sometimes* using and storing local dates/times is appropriate. If it's meant to be a timestamp, then `UtcNow` would definitely be better. Will add a comment in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

how about this?

```
var i = dc.vins.Where(aa => (aa.startDate < DateTime.Now) || (aa.Sno > 1));
```

and actually your `AND` condition should look like this,

```
var i = dc.vins.Where(aa => (aa.startDate < DateTime.Now) && (aa.Sno > 1));
```

`.Select()` is optional since you have not done any calculation or modification on `aa`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.Where(aa => aa.startDate < DateTime.Now || aa.Sno > 1 ).Select...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `||` inside your `WHERE` clause

```
var i = dc.vins.Where(aa => aa.startDate < DateTime.Now || aa.Sno > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OR operator is `||`, therefore you can try:

```
var i = dc.vins.Where(aa => aa.startDate < DateTime.Now || aa.Sno > 1);
```